# How does a Canadian sell TFSA assets in a foreign stock exchange?

Tags: stocks, canada, foreign-exchange, brokerage, tfsa

I'm using TD Waterhouse and bought some stock in my TFSA account. However, the entity was purchased by a UK company. TD Waterhouse doesn't seem to be able to sell stock on the London Stock Exchange for me.

What can I do about this situation? Are these assets stuck?

Do I need to transfer to a different brokerage?

Comment: Did you call and ask? They may not have it available on the web interface, but IIRC TD has had some global trading since 2010.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Yeah I did, and the agent seemed pretty clear they couldn't trade them for me. But I just read TD's site and it seems contradictory. I will call them again tomorrow and get back to you on this.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea You were right. There must have been a miscommunication with the first agent I talked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a misunderstanding with the original agent at TD I talked to. TD can indeed do foreign stock exchange trades, including in the TFSA, albeit for a fee ($150 was what they quoted).